# If $p$ is negative, is it true that $\ln(p^2) = 2\ln(p)$?

Tags: logarithms

Suppose, $p$ is a real negative number. However, $p^2$ is positive. Now,

$$\ln(p^2) = 2 \ln(p)\tag{1}$$

**Question:**

1. Is $(1)$ valid to write?

Comment: Probably not valid in your context.  If you start taking logs of negative numbers, you push yourself into complex numbers and then $\ln$ could have multiple values.  You have to choose a "branch" of $\ln$ and then you still have to be careful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No!

For exactly the reason you mention.

However, for $p\in\mathbb{R}$, $p\neq 0$, it is correct to write $\ln(p^2) = 2\ln(|p|)$.