# Isn't my book wrongly applying logarithm properties?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

**Problem:**

Differentiate with respect to $x$: $\sin^2(\ln(x^2))$

**My book's solution:**

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^2(\ln(x^2)))$$

$$2\sin\ln x^2.\cos\ln x^2.\frac{1}{x^2}.2x$$

$$\frac{2}{x}\sin(2\ln x^2)$$

$$\frac{2}{x}\sin(4\ln x)\tag{1}$$

**Question:**

1. Isn't $(1)$ wrong: $x$ could be a negative number, and then we wouldn't be able to apply [logarithm properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4274471/768162)?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: It should be $\frac 2x \sin(4 \ln |x|)$ instead of what's written above.

Comment: Notice everything is fine until the last step, and when taking the log of the square, we really can just pop an absolute value in there, giving @TeresaLisbon's answer.

Comment: $+1$ though can you please try to know what happens when you'll take $-$ve values and giving you the complex numbers. (Just for the sake of knowledge) and $\sin()$ of complex and all, Well @TeresaLisbon is right✌️